# WPF - Display db records into a list

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xaml

I am quite new to WPF and XAML but my background is of ASP.NET and C# so I have a vague idea of how it works.

In .net, I can use the repeater, datalist, gridview, bind to them a DataTable and output from that DataTable. I am now wanting to do the same with WPF.

Basically, I want to display simple records from a database (preferably using a DataTable as I usually work with those). The list might be something like this with two columns

- 1) Grey TV

  2) Red car

  3) Blue motorbike

I have looked around but I can't get a definitive answer on what control to use. Some people say ItemsControl and some people say DataGrid. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataGrid` is used for displaying Table-like data (Per record multiple columns). An `ItemsControl` is used to display data using your own `ItemTemplate`, in which you are unlimited in how to represent the items and in what directions or alignments.

Another good useable control for you might be a `ListView`, which works just as a `ListBox` except it doesn't have any selection logic. And you can choose between four different ways of displaying your items using the `View` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx).

In your case I would suggest using a `ListView`.

To bind any items to the control, you have to set the `DataContext` on the `UserControl` or the `Control` itself. And then bind the `ItemsSource` property to a local `List` or `Collection` using the Binding markup extension (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413.aspx). To learn more about data-binding go here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice with the ListView and managed to code a GridView inside that to show the data. Works O.K for what I want at the moment. No doubt i'll come back to this topic later.